# Disable Android Button for several hours

Tags: java, android

i need to ask that i want to disable my buttons in android studio after some time even application is closed or opened again, but actually i am new to android switched from iOS so i do not know this minor thing , help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to set property for button as "button.setClickable(false)" or if you want something else then tell

Comment: i know that but what could be the check to maintain it false until some hours pass.

Comment: Hey did I solved your problem??

Comment: it was 50 percent what i needed thank you so much for that. but I am still figuring out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for this:

Just create this shared preference:

```
  try {
                SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("my_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String stopDateString = "12/03/2017 11:19:00 AM";

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
                Date stopDate = dateFormat.parse(stopDateString);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

                if (sharedpreferences.getString("Date", "").isEmpty()) {
                    editor.putString("Date", currentTime.toString());

                    button.setClickable(false);
                }


                if (currentTime.after(stopDate)) {
                    button.setClickable(true);
                }

                editor.commit();

      } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Here "stopDataString" is date until when you want your button to be disabled.

Rest is working perfectly by this code.

Here, "button" is your instance of button.